# Rails callback not firing when building nested STI resource through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, sti

Take the following for example:

```
class Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :bars, :as => :barable, :dependent=> :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Bar < AR::Base
   belongs_to :barable, :polymorphic => true  
end

class Baz < Bar

  before_save do 
    raise "Hi"
  end

end
```

In the form for 'Foo' - I have `fields_for :bars_attributes` where a hidden field sets `type` to 'Baz'. The 'Baz' is succesfully created but the callback never fires. (It does, however, fire when manually creating a 'Baz' in the console.)

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Baz`'s callbacks will only be triggered if you create it as a `Baz` object, i.e `Baz.new(...)`.

However, you're not creating a `Baz` record, but rather a `Bar` record: `Bar.new(type: 'Baz')`.
This will only trigger `Bar`'s callbacks, even though that later on it will be treated as a `Baz`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify additonal association in your Foo.rb

```
has_many :bazs
# or
# has_many :bazs class_name: 'ModuleName::Baz' # if you scoped your child classed within some module
```

If you do that your

```
before_save do 
  raise "Hi"
end
```

will fire on for example `@current_user.bazs.build`